# git clone : Permission denied (publickey) Using Debian

Tags: git, ssh, debian, clone, config

I didn't find the solution to my problem in similar questions.

**Here is what i try to get :**

- to clone my server side git repo on a client machine

**Command that doesn't work** (from the client machine) :

```
sudo git clone myuser@servermachine:/path_to_repo/repo.git
```

**I'm getting the error:**

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Note: i can login with ssh to the server machine (from the client machine) :

```
ssh myuser@servermachine
```

--> ok i'm logged in, without being asked for a password

**What i already did :**

- 'ssh-keygen' on my client machine
- copied ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (from
  client machine) to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (on server machine)

**Additional note :**

This exact same clone command works fine from another client machine :

```
git clone myuser@servermachine:/path_to_repo/repo.git
```

It should be pretty straightforward but i'm out of idea :'(
Anyone got an idea ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with debian, but usually when I have this issue with **git** I end up writing `eval $(ssh-agent)`, `ssh-add ~/.ssh/<key_name>`

Comment: Why are you cloning with sudo ?

Comment: @AD7six : you're right, that was my mistake. I wanted to clone in /var/git which i don't have access to unless i sudo, but the cloning worked in my home dire without the sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally get it to work.

I mixed up my command with "sudo" and this was the main reason it did't work

What i did is :

- I earesed all the lines on my server machine in file ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- I cd in a folder i have access to (from client machine), like in ~/
- I started again the same command, without the sudo, and it worked, hooray !

That is :

```
git clone myuser@servermachine:/path_to_repo/repo.git
```